# Magento - hide payment methods pbridge and pbridge_ogone_direct (backend only)

Tags: magento

Magento EE 1.11:

I want to hide some obsolete payment methods in the Magento *backend*, so that they are not visible to anyone (even admin) anymore when selecting

```
System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods
```

To do this, I usually just override the unwanted payment method in a `system.xml`, like this:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <checkmo>
                    <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                </checkmo>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

clear the cache, et voilà, the methods are gone.

Today I tried to do the same with the payment methods `pbridge` and `pbridge_ogone_direct` for the very first time, but with these payment methods my standard hide method fails.

Both payment methods are still shown in the section and configurable. They stay to be still configurable even if I disable the whole `Enterprise_Pbridge` module via System -> Configuration -> Advanced.

All caches are disabled and were cleared several times.

Anybody got a clue why this happens or how to hide these bummers?

Comment: The System > Configuration > Advanced screen disables module output via blocks and module layout files, but does not exclude configuration files and module classes from being evaluated.

Does your custom module <depends /> on the offending modules?

Comment: @Ben: good idea, but the module defining the overriding `system.xml` only depends on `Mage_Core` (which depends on nothing) and `Mage_Catalog` (which depends on `Mage_Eav`, `Mage_Dataflow`, `Mage_Cms` and `Mage_Index`, but these in turn only depend on `Mage_Core` again).

Comment: And why you don't try to deactivate completely the module in the file app/etc/modules/Enterprise_Pbridge.xml you set the tag enable to false. Doesn't work? I don't have Enterprise Edition but it should be a way too.

Comment: @Diglin: because I want to make this upgrade-safe, so the next Magento Update won't break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a module with a system.xml file and declare your module as dependent on Enterprise_Pbridge (assuming that is the correct `modules` value):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- module decl. in app/etc/modules -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Enterprise_Pbridge />
            </depends>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

You can also disable the Enterprise_Pbridge module directly by changing its active flag to false - the safest way of course is to create a module registration file which is loaded, alphabetically, after the module declaration file that you are trying to disable, eg. `app/etc/modules/Z.xml` with the following xpath: `config/modules/Enterprise_Pbridge/active`.

Comment: Oh, snap! You mean to force my modules `system.xml` to be evaluated after the one of `<Enterprise_Pbridge>`? Of course! Tested. Works like a charme, thank you^^

Comment: Excellent! I meant to say that disabling the module outright can be problematic, as often times modules can be coupled in less-than-obvious ways. Thanks for testing & reporting back.